# pyqt5 managing layout with labels

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

Im trying to add couple of labels to my layout and those items needs to be adjacent.

The below code keeps them adjacent but its in the middle of the layout. I want those labels to be in the top.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QDialog, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.Qt import QHBoxLayout, QWindow, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(hlayout)

        a1 = QLabel('label1')
        a2 = QLabel('label2')
        hlayout.addWidget(a1)
        hlayout.addWidget(a2)
        hlayout.addStretch(2)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        vlayout.addStretch(1)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Lines')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
#     ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A layout must be inside a widget, but in your case the `QVBoxLayout` is not denoted by any widget.

The idea is that you have the following structure:

```
widget
└── vlayout
    └── hlayout
        ├── a1
        └── a2
```

Using that structure we have the following:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        a1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label1', )
        a2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label2')

        hlayout.addWidget(a1)
        hlayout.addWidget(a2)
        hlayout.addStretch()
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        vlayout.addStretch()

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Lines')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
#     ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]